# How to compile a C99 source on vc++2008 but without changing the original function？

Tags: c, arrays, c99, visual-c++-2008

Such as:

```
enum {
    SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_INIT = 101,
    SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_RESET,
    SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_SET,
    SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_MOVE,
    SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_HIDE,
    SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_TRAIL,
    SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_INVAL_ONE,
    SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_INVAL_ALL,

    SPICE_MSG_END_CURSOR
};

static const spice_msg_handler cursor_handlers[] = {
    [ SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_INIT ]              = cursor_handle_init,
    [ SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_RESET ]             = cursor_handle_reset,
    [ SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_SET ]               = cursor_handle_set,
    [ SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_MOVE ]              = cursor_handle_move,
    [ SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_HIDE ]              = cursor_handle_hide,
    [ SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_TRAIL ]             = cursor_handle_trail,
    [ SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_INVAL_ONE ]         = cursor_handle_inval_one,
    [ SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_INVAL_ALL ]         = cursor_handle_inval_all,
};
```

Which I couldn't even understand what did it mean.
It couldn't pass on vc++2008,How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

That's called **designated initializers** which is introduced in C99. For example, to initialize an array, you can specify the array indices in any order:

```
int a[6] = { [4] = 29, [2] = 15 };
```

is equivalent to

```
int a[6] = { 0, 0, 15, 0, 29, 0 };
```

So in your example, with the definition of enums, `cursor_handlers` is initialized with `101` elements of `0`, then several other values.

The problem is, VC++2008 doesn's support most of C99 features, including this one. So you'll have to either initialize the array with fixed order(the old C89 way), or initialize the array with all `0` and assign the appropriate elements.

Too bad the array is `const`, so you'll have to use the C89 way:

```
static const spice_msg_handler cursor_handlers[] = {0, 0, /*...all 101 0s*/, cursor_handle_init, /*...*/}
```

If it's not `const`, you can use this:

```
static spice_msg_handler cursor_handlers[SPICE_MSG_END_CURSOR] = {};
cursor_handlers[SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_INIT] = cursor_handle_init;
cursor_handlers[SPICE_MSG_CURSOR_RESET] = cursor_handle_reset;
//...
```